# Convergence of a multiple numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration

I would like to define the following function $F(A,\nu)$, which is the result of a numerical integration, and needs the following function definitions.

```
χ[x_] := (1 - x^2) Exp[-x^2/2.]
v1[x_, T_, A_, ν_] := 
 Sqrt[2 ν A] (-Tanh[Sqrt[A/ 2. ν] (x - Sqrt[-Sqrt[A] T])] + 
    Tanh[Sqrt[A/ 2. ν] (x + Sqrt[-Sqrt[A] T])])
u1[x_, T_, A_, ν_] := v1[x, T, A, ν]/v1[0., T, A, ν]
P[x_, T_] := -x Abs[x]/(8. T^2)

F[A_?NumericQ, ν_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  P[x, T] u1[x, T, A, ν] P[y, T] u1[y, T, A, ν] χ[
    x - y], {y, - Infinity, Infinity}, {x, - Infinity, 
   Infinity}, {T, -Sqrt[A], -1/Sqrt[A]}, WorkingPrecision -> 6]
```

$F(A,\nu)$ is the integral of the product of the function $P(x,T)\, u_1(x,T,A,\nu)$ (displayed in the image) at two different points, x and y, and a kernel $(1-x^2) \exp(-x^2/2)$. The image was generated for $T=-10.$, $A=10.$ and $\nu=100.$  (these are typical values for these variables, $T$ is always negative and $A$ is always larger than 1).

[image: Profile of function integrated]

The evaluation of this function takes a long time and returns some numerical warnings. For instance,

```
F[1000., 100.]
```

returns these messages:

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect 
>   one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly 
>   oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has 
>   increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease 
>   monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the 
>   following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified 
>   precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a 
>   (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. 
>   Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might 
>   lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 
>   288.76382016096916666703282912247185710989612309233822429`56. and 
>   5.4011184087238421426993848117761301626885820484484066096`56. for the 
>   integral and error estimates.

What options can I use for better convergence of this integral, and how can I decide which method is the best, from looking at the properties of the integrand?

Comment: Your working precision is too small. Experiment using higher working precisions and small precision goals.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish setting `WorkingPrecision` less than machine precision?  In any case if you want to go to high precision you,ll need to specify exact values for your literals ( make `8.` `8`, etc)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks! I thought something like that might be in place...

Comment: @AntonAntonov Oops, I misread the limits.  `0` is not in the `T` interval, so the integrand is ok (or if not, I haven't discovered the pathological part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, the code provides results that demonstrate the need for more detailed investigation.

#### Re-definition

The re-defintion uses exact numbers and adds options argument to `F`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

χ[x_] := (1 - x^2) Exp[-x^2/2]
v1[x_, T_, A_, ν_] := 
 Sqrt[2 ν A] (-Tanh[Sqrt[A/2 ν] (x - Sqrt[-Sqrt[A] T])] + 
    Tanh[Sqrt[A/2 ν] (x + Sqrt[-Sqrt[A] T])])
u1[x_, T_, A_, ν_] := v1[x, T, A, ν]/v1[0, T, A, ν]
P[x_, T_] := -x Abs[x]/(8 T^2)

F[A_?NumericQ, ν_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 NIntegrate[
  P[x, T] u1[x, T, A, ν] P[y, T] u1[y, T, A, ν] χ[x - y], 
  {y, -∞, ∞}, {x, -∞, ∞}, {T, -Sqrt[A], -1/Sqrt[A]}, opts]
```

#### Experiments

Using the default working precision produces result that seems to be wrong:

```
In[63]:= AbsoluteTiming[F[1000, 100]]

Out[63]= {5.68169, 288.231}
```

Here is a result with higher working precision and denser sampling points:

```
In[64]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 F[1000, 100, WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
  MinRecursion -> 2, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
 ]

Out[64]= {72.3681, 292.119919516539460106135415685}
```

And one more without singularity handling:

```
In[65]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 F[1000, 100, WorkingPrecision -> 60, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
  MinRecursion -> 2, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, 
    "SingularityHandler" -> None}]
 ]

Out[65]= {65.9541, 293.123327189195721528823498643979792005706149710632238819309}
```

Having these kind of different results means that the integral has some pathological parts (narrow peaks, oscillations, singular points/curves...) This have to be investigated further and [`NIntegrate`'s advanced documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateOverview.html) provides a good start.